# Importaciones cruzadas en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

En mi proyecto Django tengo 2 apps, como lo muestra el siguiente mapa:

```
Django/ProyectoWeb/Apps/
├── Catedra
└── Usuarios
```

Sin detallar mucho:

- La Catedra tiene un único modelo llamado Comisión.
- La Usuarios tiene 2 modelos llamados Alumno, Docente.

El problema está en que la comisión tiene un Docente de encargado y el alumno tiene una comisión asignada. Por esto tengo que importar de la siguiente forma:

- En apps.Catedras.models importo: `from Apps.Usuarios.models import Docente`
- En apps.Usuarios.models importo: `from Apps.Catedras.models import comision`

Pero al hacer estas importaciones, y correr el `makemigrations`, me dice que no es posible realizar las importaciones.

No se si se entiende. Cualquier cosa trato de aclararlo mejor

## Edito

> Apps.usuarios.models

```
from __future__                         import unicode_literals

from django.db                          import models
from django.contrib.auth.models         import User

from Apps.catedras.models               import ComisionCatedra
from Apps.choices                       import (
                                            ESPECIALIDADES_CHOICES,
                                            MATERIAS_CHOICES,
                                            )
class Alumno(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True)
    dni = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    legajo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    comision = models.ForeignKey(ComisionCatedra)
    especialidad = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ESPECIALIDADES_CHOICES)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, null=True)


class Docente(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    dni = models.PositiveIntegerField() 


class Laboratorista(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    dni = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

> Apps.catedras.models

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

from Apps.choices                       import (
                                            DIAS_SEMANA_CHOICES,
                                            ESPECIALIDADES_CHOICES,
                                            MATERIAS_CHOICES,
                                            )
from Apps.usuarios.models               import (
                                            Alumno,
                                            Docente,
                                            Laboratorista,
                                            )


class ComisionCatedra(models.Model):
    numero = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    especialidad = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ESPECIALIDADES_CHOICES)
    materia = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MATERIAS_CHOICES)
    titular = models.ManyToManyField(Docente)
    adjunto = models.ManyToManyField(Docente)
    jtp = models.ManyToManyField(Docente)
    ayudantes = models.ManyToManyField(Docente)
```

El mensaje en la consola al ejecutar `makemigrations` es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jorger/Django/fisicaweb/Apps/laboratorio/models.py", line 16, in <module>
    from Apps.usuarios.models               import (
  File "/home/jorger/Django/fisicaweb/Apps/usuarios/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Apps.catedras.models               import ComisionCatedra
  File "/home/jorger/Django/fisicaweb/Apps/catedras/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Apps.usuarios.models               import (
ImportError: cannot import name Alumno
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el mensaje de error original? Si es posible incluye las partes más relevantes de la traza del error que aparece cuando ejecutas las migraciones. También incluye la definición de los modelos, porque el error de migración no ocurre al importar un modelo sino al usarlo.

Comment: @toledano Espero haber puesto lo que me pediste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto suele pasar cuando tienes problemas de importación circular (el módulo A importa algo de B, el módulo B importa algo de A).

Lo más sencillo es usar los nombres de los modelos usando la notación `app.Modelo`:

```
class ComisionCatedra(models.Model):
    # ...
    titular = models.ManyToManyField('usuarios.Docente')
    adjunto = models.ManyToManyField('usuarios.Docente')
    jtp = models.ManyToManyField('usuarios.Docente')
    ayudantes = models.ManyToManyField('usuarios.Docente')
```

No necesitas hacer el `import`, de esto se encarga Django internamente. Lo mismo harías en tus otros modelos.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan pronto, me resulto muy útil tu respuesta, pero solo para aclarar, para que funcione le agregue `ayudantes = models.ManyToManyField('usuarios.Docente', related_name='Ayudante')`, y la verdad no se porque.

Comment: @JorgeErnestoRONCONI cierto, tienes que pasarles nombres distintos para la relación inversa.